# Xdebug with PhpStorm won't stop at random breakpoints

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I recently installed Xdebug on my server and I have a very strange problem :

Sometimes, Xdebug don't stop a breakpoint, sometimes it does. It is very confusing because I spent time investigating why PHP didn't go to a certain point of my code, before understanding that it was only Xdebug that "choose" randomly which breakpoint it want to stop, and which it doesn't want. I tried to close PhpStorm and restart it, and **sometimes** some of the breakpoints work again and other doesn't anymore. It seems that its completely random.

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.1, and Xdebug 2.7. I did the PhpStorm Xdebug validator that told me everything is OK with the Xdebug config.

I'm using Xdebug with "zero-configuration", calling scripts from Chrome with the extension. Do you think it can be a bug of PhpStorm?

Comment: There is no way to tell what is happening there without seeing the code/where you put the breakpoint and other details/nuances. It simply could be your code (human mistake), placing breakpoint at wrong line (e.g. multiline statements are not safe) etc. The best I can suggest (the most complex solution) is to [contact JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731), providing them your sample code, steps to reproduce and xdebug log.

Comment: Do you think it can be caused by internet poor connection ? I have very poor WiFi connection in my room. I just approached the router and it looks better. But I will upload a screen recording as soon as the bug get back

Comment: TBH: no ideas, but I doubt that it will be an issue in the middle of the debug session. When Xdebug tries to establish connection -- yes, it might be the issue as Xdebug waits for 200ms only, but during already established debug session ... not sure that such restriction is used.

Comment: Other few ideas (rather random ideas without knowing your code/setup in details): you may have some code caching (sometimes OPCache may cause issues), old code (e.g. changed code locally but forgot to upload latest version to server), misconfiguration (e.g. making conditional breakpoint). Overall (based on my knowledge of PhpStorm forum threads/tickets for similar subjects) it's unlikely to be an IDE issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I caught on the bug "on tape" in this video : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I3G886T-BTNHgYp7PeXMVFI1saAof0TK 
1/ how to see / disable this cache to see if its working ? 2/ Code has been successfully transfered to remote server before debug session

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see anything on your video -- pic size is too tall for my standard orientation monitor so I do not even see the code yet figuring out what might be happening there.

Comment: I will try to do a better video as soon as possible. Thanks for your comments:)